# What is the equivalent of Java's final in Rust?

Tags: java, rust, keyword

What is the Rust equivalent of Java's `final` for methods, properties, etc...

Comment: You are likely being downvoted because it appears you haven't done any research. Uses of `final` include subclassing (Rust doesn't have), all variables may only be assigned once (default in Rust). These are aspects that you run into immediately upon doing any Rust. Additionally, the "etc..." is kind of like saying "I'm too lazy to list out all the uses, you do all the hard work for me".

Comment: It's a low effort question, reeking of XY problem (you presumably ask because you want to achieve a specific thing that you'd achieve in Java with `final`, but instead of asking about that thing you ask about the Java language feature) and doesn't even make much sense when one is familiar with Rust.

Comment: Shepmaster: I have read entire page of its wiki and according to wiki, rust supports object-oriented programming. my question was about all of the situations I can use final which includes preventing overriding.

Comment: Object-oriented programming doesn't require subclassing; that's just the form that many programmers are familiar with.

Comment: you *can* actually override trait methods with default implementations, so the question make all sense in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `final` for methods does not make sense because Rust doesn't have implementation inheritance.
- `final` for properties does not exist because it does not mesh well with *inherited mutability*. In most cases, properties `a.x` are mutable if and only if their owner `a` is mutable. While one can opt into more mutability (this is then called *inherent* mutability), the converse (a field being immutable within an otherwise mutable value) was considered too much hassle to be worthwhile. This is partly because Rust doesn't default to reference semantics, so you can always overwrite the "object" entirely even if you can't overwrite individual fields.
- `final` for local variables is similar to the *default behavior* in Rust (variables are, by default, deeply immutable). There are differences, primarily that a `final` local of reference type only prevents changing the *reference* but not *the referenced object* — Rust has inherited mutability instead, see above.